# Is it okay to have a .gpg file under sources.list.d?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, gnupg

I have the following file under sources.list.d

```
goutham@goutham-11-11:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
cuda-ubuntu2204-12-3-local.list  gazebo-stable.list              google-chrome.list     obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-jammy.list  ros2.list        ros.list              ubuntu-esm-infra.list
gazebo.list                      git-core-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list  google-cloud-sdk.list  pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg            ros-latest.list  ubuntu-esm-apps.list
```

when i try to update using:  `sudo apt update`

I get the following error message.

```
N: Ignoring file 'pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/ jammy: /usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/gazebo-archive-keyring.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

what is the reason behind this, please help me in the comment section without refercing to other posted questions of the same type, as I am not understanding and I am completely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: The reason is because `sources.list.d` is supposed to only have **lists** of sources, not GPG files.  You should create a folder for `/etc/apt/keyrings` and put the keys in there and then specify the Signed-By paths to refer to the files under `/etc/apt/keyrings` if you don't want to modify `/usr/share/` stuff.